# wcf service call over net.pipe is breaking with The server has rejected the client credentials

Tags: wcf

I am trying to deploy existing web application and wcf services on windows server 2016 IIS server. When application is trying to connect wcf service using net.pipe protocol with "Transport security mode and EncryptAndSing" protection level". it is breaking with "The server has rejected the client credentials" error. Detail error is mentioned below.

Service is exposed using host name (net.pipe://[hostname]/service/..svc)

Error Stack trace:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: SecurityNegotiationException 
    Exception message: The server has rejected the client credentials.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
```

1) Unsecured calls are working( Security mode = "None")
2) If we replace hostname with host IP. It works.

Since we have load balance environment with multiple servers. So we want to expose service with [hostname]. Secured calls for net pipe endpoint exposed using hostname in address is expected to be working.

This is working as expected on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: What is the specifically client credential? Do you have enable the corresponding authentication mode in IIS authentication module e.g. window authentication.

Comment: Yes. Windows Authentication is enabled.

Comment: It worked after adding <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="SomeValue" />
        </identity> in client endpoint configuration

Comment: Thanks for sharing your progress of the issue. So far as I know, the configuration will automatically add the option if you call the service by adding service reference.